# C# System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox Text does not update after a selection change

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, selecteditem

I am using a simple ComboBox in C#.  I put in 3 items: "apple", "banana", and "orange".  Here is what I do:

1. Click on the comboBox to view the drop-down.  I see all 3 items fine.  Then I select "banana" via mouse-left-click
2. The comboBox now shows "banana" which is correct so far
3. Now I click on the comboBox again to view the drop-down.  I move my mouse to highlight "orange".  I then hit TAB to move off the comboBox
4. The comboBox is still showing "banana"
5. However, when I get the selectedItem, it's "orange"

Is this the expected behaviour?  If I hightlight "orange" and tab out, I would expect either:

1. selectedItem should remain the same (meaning tab out does not trigger a selection change) or...
2. the comboBox should display "orange" since the selection has changed

I overcome this by using the `comboBox.Leave` event handler to manually set the text field to be the `selectedItem` however, I would like to know if I am missing some fundamental concepts here.

It seems logical that if selection changes, the `comboBox.Text` should reflect this without any manual intervention?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: This doesn't happen if the list is using the DropDownList style.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have it figured out correctly. In a combobox, the selecteditem does not have to be the same as the text. This allows non-items to be entered in the text of the combobox. You can just ignore the SelectedItem and use the text field.